# How to show text at the center of a TextBlock without changing its width?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, textblock

I was thinking is there any way to show the texts at the center of a `TextBlock` without changing its width?
I've already tried this:

```
  <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
```

As i said it changes width of the `TextBlock`,but in some cases i need to Stretch `TextBlock` to it's parent,assume that the `TextBlock` has border so i need to make it Stretch to it's parent.
Actually i need to do this on the `TextBlock` that is placed inside the `DataGridTextColumn`,so please don't give answers that i can't use!like using other controls or something like that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`TextBlock.TextAlignment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.textalignment.aspx)`="Center"`